How can I simplify or accelerate my learning of sheet music?
I've only been at the piano (or rather a 61-key keyboard) for about a month now. However, just out of curiosity, I wanted to ask what skills one must require to read and play using sheet music fluently. Is there any simpler way of reading it? how can I learn sheet music?

Although one may not like to hear it, acquiring any technical skill requires a lot of practice besides sufficient guidance from a competent teacher, and by a lot I really mean a lot, roughly 1000 hr for basic proficiency and 10000 hr to reach expert level. So if you spend 3 hr a day consistently you should still accept that you will need 1 yr to reach basic proficiency. Just put in the necessary time and effort and the results will follow.

@user21820 - that is very much dependant on the way one practises, the propensity for learning, and a load of other factors. Results will not always follow, as if by magic, don't kid anyone.

@Tim: Did you miss "sufficient guidance from a competent teacher"?

@user21820 - no, I caught that. But left to one's own devices, I agree it'll take a long time, like ages. And when that competent teacher is actually present, that's when the best progress will be  made. But that's only 1hr per week for the lucky ones. My teachers were 'competent', but didn't help one jot with my sight reading, alas.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

I have edited the title to make this question on topic here.

Here are the things most helpful to me when I was learning to read — not in any particular order:

Remember that the goal is to read music, not notes.

Read from extremely simple pieces. "Simple" means that you can read the pitches, the rhythm, the articulation, the dynamics, both hands all at once the first time. After one time through, but not more than three, you should be able to have a good feel for the music. Even the simplest exercise can be made musical, if only to a small degree.

Learn to recognize intervals at sight and feel them in your hand, with appropriate fingering. Most any beginning method book will have exercises to this effect. The one I'm most familiar with is Francis Clark's Keyboard Musician for the Adult Beginner, which I recommend unreservedly.

Learn to clap rhythms while keeping the beat, independently of reading the pitches. For example, tap the beat with one foot while clapping the rhythm. There are many exercise books for studying rhythm. I recommend The Rhythm Book by Richard Hoffman. (There is at least one other book by the same title, but different author.)


Once these basics are sufficiently ingrained, Then the next steps involve recognizing groups and patters of notes, especially scales and chords. See Acquiring advanced level sight reading for next steps. (Although the title says "advanced", the suggestions are perfectly appropriate and doable after sufficiently mastering the steps described in this post.)

Doesn't seem like enough for me to write a separate answer that I'd add that reading music better is the same process as reading language better: keep reading every day and your reading improves, and move on to harder and longer pieces slowly over time.

Written music can be split into two separate, really unrelated, parts, surprisingly.
The pitches themselves - the actual notes that need to be played, and the duration of those notes - how long each will last when played.
So sight reading can be divided into two (for now) separate entities.
The duration first! Learn to clap, tap, snort, whatever, the dots in their respective timings. If the timing is incorrect, even if the notes are perfect, a different tune will be produced. (Try playing 'Happy birthday' with different duration notes if you're not convinced!). So, getting to the capability of playing or just tapping the notes in rhythm while keeping a constant tempo, maybe with a foot, is paramount.
Note pitches themselves: knowing the diatonic notes of the key the piece is in is pretty important. I know on this site there are many questions relating to 'foreign' notes, but by and large, those diatonics will be making up most pieces. So, knowing scales, arpeggios and such like will help enormously here. That will not only tell which notes to expect, but which ones not to expect - the chromatics.
Learn to recognise note clusters, particularly l.h. chords. Their shapes will aid quick response. Think about it: We recognise the shape of the word wheelbarrow as we read it, we don't usually spell it out phonetically. Again, with chords, be aware which chords are most likely to be involved, mainly l.h., so we can plot the geography of the piece. Along with that goes knowing the inversions of those chords.
Completely different: take simple tunes, and do the opposite from sight-reading. Write them down on manuscript. Starting with their rhythms, then add their pitches. A sort of reverse sight-reading.
And finally, remember that once you become a great sight-reader, you'll not have to spend as much time on new pieces, working out what they should sound like! A great incentive!

Written music has only two parts?

@Aaron - obviously, I'm  talking in very simplistic terms. By parts, I mean elements, not straying into satb, etc. Dynamics et al will come much later for beginners. Thanks for reading!

Dynamics coming "much later" depends purely on the teacher and the method. (And, you're welcome, of course. I think not enough posts get read.)

@Aaron - from experience, I think there's enough on a beginner's plate to deal with what is in my answer. Some students will automatically make something sound musical, others might hardly reach those heady heights. But initially, if the notes and rhythm aren't right, there's no point in trying to make anything sound musical - the icing on the top.

Music is the foundation of music. Would you rather hear a musical performance with some missed notes, or a note-perfect performance that's robotic? From experience, beginners are perfectly capable of handling dynamics and articulation.

@Aaron - moot point. Missed notes are listenable, but wrongly played notes in wrong timing would not be so good. Of course, robotic is unacceptable to us musos, as well. Maybe a question is heralded...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The same way (as the old joke says) you get to Carnegie Hall: practice!!
Of course, you first need to understand the basics of the notation you're reading: all the standard ways to indicate pitch and rhythm, as described in other answers.  (Then, as you improve, you can take account of dynamics, phrasing, articulation, and other details too.)
But once you know that, then I don't think there's any trick to it: the only way to get fluent is simply to do it — and do it a lot.  That's how we learn to read English (or any other written language), after all; the more you do it, the easier it gets, the less you need to consciously think about it, and the more you can take in at a glance without having to puzzle out the details.  And as with any skill, it takes time and repetition to build up the necessary connections and pathways in your brain.
Of course, for some people this comes easier than others…
(I always had trouble sight-reading.  But that vastly improved when I joined a vocal group as a young adult, and found myself trying to sight-read complex pieces, one voice per part, at full speed, often in foreign languages…  At first, I had trouble even following where everyone was!  But over the next few months my sight-singing improved tremendously, and I'm still pretty good at it.  (For a single line, anyway — I'm still lousy at piano music…)  So lots of practice really can bring huge benefits.)
So, I'd suggest getting hold of as much new music as you can (at a level that you can decipher without help, however slowly — it can be much easier than the music you study), picking a new piece every day if you can manage, and having a bash at it.  (And I use the term ‘bash’ advisedly!  For this, it doesn't matter how you sound — only that you're trying to read the music.)  Once you get good enough, try using a metronome and playing at a steady speed (even if that's really slow).
It'll be painful at first, but if you keep it up (for several months at least), then you're bound to improve!
Of course, this goes hand-in-hand with other musical skills: technical ability on the keyboard; understanding of style, musical line, articulation, etc.; and all the related skills that let you understand exactly what the composer intended and turn that into a satisfying experience for you and anyone listening.  Those skills can take a lifetime to master, so don't be disheartened if progress seems slow.  But if you keep practising, then you'll be moving in the right direction.

All that's fair enough, but when one sight reads at home, in isolation, how does one know one is actually reading the dots accurately?

@Tim The same way you know if you're spending time learning a piece, I think.  As I said, you need to be building up your other musical skills too.  Sight-reading in front of a teacher will give you all the feedback you want, of course; but as you train your ear, you'll often be able to tell when you get it wrong on your own too.

I aske the question, as I sometimes get the timing wrong by myself, and as you know, a series of notes in the right key can still sound good with the wrong timing!

@Tim YouTube.  Go to YouTube.  Type in the name of the tune, and somebody, somewhere will have recorded it.  If what you are playing is different, it's probably you that's wrong.

@SimonB - playing by listening to recordings is what I've done for the past 65 yrs, which is why my sight reading isn't as good as it should be. My premise is that, for me that's a faster way in which to get a song down. So, for me, it's easier to cut out the sight-reading part, and just listen. But in a reading band, that's just not an option. I'm expected to look at the dots and play them right, No time for reference.

It used to be said that there were two sorts of musicians: those who find it easier to play by ear, and those who prefer reading notation.  I gather it's more complicated than that, but there's at least an element of truth: I've always been a player-by-ear.  But my experience shows that, whichever comes more naturally, you can get good at the other with enough practice.

@Tim I don't think Simon is suggesting listening to a recording as a substitute for sight-reading, but as a way to check how well you did after trying to sight-read.

When I learned classical guitar, the books we used combined sheet notation with the actual instrument practice - i.e. starting from lesson #1, the instruction of what to play was simply using sheet notation (as opposed to something that would be more "simple" - i.e., tabulature, in the case of the guitar), and the notation was in fact explicitly explained as well as we went along.
Practicing the hand/finger movements together with the the mental exercise seems to work very well. In fact, wasn't there some news that they stopped using tablets in early school, and returned to analog writing in some of the nordic countries? I bet that was at least partly because neurologically, mental activities, when combined with physical activities, get ingrained better. (Just guessing here.)
Back to he topic: make sure you get your lessons from sheet music, and play whatever you can read. Eventually, it will "click", and eventually you should be able to read more complex music than you can play (the complexity of the notation is much less than the complexity of actually playing, eventually). At the point, the reading part is a moot point, it will just happen. If whatever book you are learning from does not contain info on the notation (in a didactic manner), get one. If you are not actually using a book, but more from random YouTube videos... figure out what's the current standard method for learning piano the old-fashioned way - people have come up with very systematic ways over the centuries; that stuff does work.

Some of the simpler things that speeds me up when reading pitches:
Understand the key sign convention that follows the circle of fifths.
Anchor in your memory lines and ledger lines by name, I find the ones defining the clef and the top and bottom and the ledger ones the most necessary.
Feel the geography of the piano. Learn all the names of the white keys on the piano. Feel the shape of the piano near them. Keep one of your fingers on the note and feel around with the others for as far as you can stretch. Don't be afraid to have some fingers crossed, you want to feel as much as you can. I think of the small clusters of whole note connected keys as a valley or a boat, where the ends are like peaks or edges of the boat. Stuff like that.
Know that fingers can be named like for example PIMAC, and that there exists names for shorter one to five note scales, this can aid you to have a nickname for the "hand shapes" you use. You could also learn to name the hand shape after chords related to it.
Learn which two pairs of notes are adjacent for each key signature. Realize that two steps up or two steps down the circle of fifth moves your hand shape one whole step up or down. Learn this both geographically on the piano, but also on the sheet music (which line and open space that are adjacent by one half step). This is so you have a better chance of reading the quality of the intervals.
I found it useful to encode the circle of fifth pattern using interval numbers modulo the octave. I usually make tables in excel with for example P5 steps up and b2 steps right and then fat the diatonic ones.
Sorry for rambling but some of these things were eureka moments for me so wanted to jot them down. Good luck.
